# using nginx reverse proxy for flash amf requests, any pitfalls?

Tags: actionscript, nginx, reverse-proxy, amf

my understanding of amf (which isnt all that great) is that the requests come in binary format.

any pitfalls to be aware of when using a reverse proxy to pipe these requests to another server, and back out?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMF communications are wrapped in an HTTP POST to reduce processing complications. As such, you should have not troubles using a proxy.